# Emberjs 2 remove CORS and CSP

Tags: ember.js, cors, content-security-policy

I'm trying EmberJs 2 and found a problem making Ajax requests. I have read a lot of questions on stackOverflow and still can't resolve the problem. 
I access the emberapp from http://localhost:4200 and my API server(PHP) is in http://localhost. Below is a screen shoot of the console.

What should I do step by step? Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

routes/users.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(){
        console.log($.getJSON('http://localhost/api'));
    }
});
```

environment.js:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    /*......*/
    contentSecurityPolicy:{
        'connect-src':" 'self' http://localhost ",
        'font-src' : " 'self' http://localhost "
    }
    /*......*/

  };
```

This is in PHP localhost/api/index.php:

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$array = array(
    'name'=>"Firstname",
    'lastname' => 'Lastname',
    'age'=>'23'
);

echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ember server --proxy http://localhost:80
```

Will proxy all AJAX requests to that address.

Comment: I tried and nothing was resolved, still the same problem

Comment: How are you doing your GET?

Comment: Try `$.getJSON('/api')`. You should be able to remove the `contentSecurityPolicy` you've defined and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header as well. You don't need them for what you're doing.

Comment: I removed the line : header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); from PHP,

I removed also 
contentSecurityPolicy:{
        'connect-src':" 'self' http://localhost ",
        'font-src' : " 'self' http://localhost "
    }

And changed the url in the get request: $.getJSON('/api').

But it show me Content Security Violations

Comment: I only see CORS errors in your screenshot, can you show us the content security violations?

Comment: but when Iet the contentSecurityPolicy:{
  'connect-src':" 'self' http://localhost "
 }, on the environment.js it works perfectly. Thanks for the help. If you want you can write down an answer, and I will check it as the right answer so it can help the others with the same problem like me.

Comment: As long as it works! Happy to help. And this is an answer already. :-)

Comment: Anyway this was the screenshoot when I removed the contentSecurityPolicy in the enviroment.js : http://imgur.com/dQYQbCV